# {% raw %} inside of liquid block

Tags: jekyll, liquid, mustache

Using mustache.js on a Jekyll site, is it possible to use a mustache variable within a liquid code block?

Something like:

```
{% if liquidVar == {% raw %}{{ mustacheVar }}{% endraw %} %}
  // do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Your workflow is unclear. Why would you set a Mustache variable in a Liquid control tag ?

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided doesn't make logical sense. The liquid `{% if %}` will be processed only during build, a runtime javascript variable won't be available then.

That aside, if you are using mustache.js with Jekyll you will want to change the mustasche delimiters.

See https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#custom-delimiters

Your best bet is to override it globally. This will let you avoid having to pollute your code with `{% raw %}` blocks everywhere. The following will let you use `{| variable-name |}` for mustache variables

```
Mustache.tags = [ '{|', '|}' ];
```

It is possible to override it at a template level, but there you will need to escape it

```
{% raw %}{{={| |}=}}{% endraw %}
```